# NumPy: efficiently assign a row/column to an array

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I want to assign two values, `x` and `y` to an existing matrix of shape `(100,100,2)`. The normal way of assigning them to a row/column would be:

```
my_array[row, column] = [x, y]
```

But I have found that the following is much more efficient:

```
my_array[row, column, 0] = x
my_array[row, column, 1] = y
```

Which totally makes sense due to the fact that the former must create a list/tuple and then assign it, while the later just assigns to a particular index without intermediate data structures being created.

I was wondering if there is a more compact way of expressing the former while preserving the efficiency of the later, something like:

```
np.assign(my_array[row,column], x, y)
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Also, try out `= np.array([x, y])` for efficiency testing.

Comment: If there was a function such as `np.assign`, it sounds like it would have to either form an intermediate data structure from its arguments OR loop over the argument values.  Probably neither of these would be quite as fast as direct assignment. However in most cases, array assignment is not going to be the slowest part of the code.

Comment: Just guessing here: are you by any chance changing *every* cell in the array to an `x,y` value? Or perhaps only cells that have a specific `x,y` value? If it is the latter, take a look at this: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that comes to mind as an exact answer is this:

```
my_array[row, column, 0], my_array[row, column, 1] = x, y
```